# How do you structure your business logic folders?

Tags: c#, logic, structure, implementation

I've been reading a lot around how you guys organise your business logic, and it's evident that the view is there's no wrong implementation as long as it's decoupled from the other layers within your application.

My question relates to the physical implementation of your layer rather than conceptual. How do you prefer to actually implement the structure of your business logic layer?

I tend to have a 'services' folder which holds persistence and query service classes for each of the modules/departments of the application.

What's your preference on the folder structure of the business layer specifically, so if you were to view it from a solution explorer, what folders and sub folders do you tend/prefer to create?

Edit:

I'm asking what you prefer to label your folders as. I call my module folders 'services', I've also seen them labelled as 'EntityHelpers'.

Comment: This is opinion based (which is off-topic according to [help/on-topic]

Comment: I do believe this is one of those questions where "It depends" is a correct answer. If you can handle everything in one folder do it, if you feel some separation is needed go for it.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the fundamental question of architecture: "I have a lot of logic...how do I structure it?" It is hard to answer such a general question in brief since numerous books have written about various aspects of this problem

The fundamental design principles: Layering, slicing, separation of concerns, single-responsibility, high-cohesion-low-coupling and so on should be applied at all levels of the architecture, not just the top level.

Comment: My question relates to the folder structure on the business layer specifically, so if you were to view it from a solution explorer, what folders and sub folders do you tend to create?

Answer (score 0):

A "folder" wouldn't be over simplistic to organise your solution. Although, if you are working with in a relatively small problem, it should be just enough. Thinking about layering and keep your business logic tight and coerent, I would suggest you to read more about DDD from Eric Evans.

You would create your business logic in your domain layer, decoupling it from view(not necessarily web), application and infrastructure logic.

Check out the Microsoft [example](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/src/Services/Ordering), it captures the essence of DDD.
There is also the Vaughn Vernon DDD book, who gives am practical approach to understand it use.